# Save a tibble with list columns to disk

Tags: r, tidyverse, feather

I would like to save to disk a `tibble` that has list-columns (for later use inside R only). Ideally I'd like a fast binary format like `feather`, however, it doesn't seem to support list cols:

```
test <- tibble(a= list(c(1,2), c(3,4)))
feather::write_feather(test, 'test.csv')
```

> Error in writeFeather(x, path) : Not implemented: a is a list

I was expecting the methods in the `readr` package to be able to handle this, but none of the ones I've tried seem to be able to.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `saveRDS` and  `readRDS` functions:

```
library(tibble)
test <- tibble(a= list(c(1,2), c(3,4)))
saveRDS(test, "c:/test.rds")
test_2 <- readRDS("c:/test.rds"))
identical(test, test_2)
```

In the `readr` package there are `read_rds` and `write_rds` functions, which even allow compression to be set.

Comment: Sadly when you read a tibble saved in  a RDS file, strings columns are read like factor data type

Answer (score 2):

My experience of the `tidyverse` is that they do not work with columns containing lists. For example, `filter` from dplyr does not work correctly for lists inside `data.frame`s. So, for the operations that are not supported you are stuck with functions that do support this.

If you are simply looking for a way to store any R object on disk, I would recommend you check out `save` or `saveRDS` (and `load` and `readRDS`). This serializes R objects to a binary format. Note that this is only useful as storage between R sessions, and is not interoperable with other analysis tools such as Python or SPSS.

Comment: Are you referring to base R's `write.csv`? Because that also gave me an error: `unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'`.
I guess for now I'll have to normalize my data.

Comment: I was referencing that, but I agree even that is not a good format. I think a simple binary format would be to use `saveRDS`. This is however not interchangeable with other software packages, and is purely for use between R sessions.

Comment: And indeed, you can also reduce your values to a single one.

Comment: You can use `filter` on list.frames, you just have to use the `mutate`/`map` step to apply the `filter`.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra: Thanks, reducing to a single value wouldn't have worked well in this case, but `saveRDS` was exactly what I was looking for. Quite surprised I've never encountered it before. :)